# How to extract Open Graph info from TXT file?

Tags: php, json, parsing, text-files

I have a TXT file containing some facebook Open Graph info like this:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Avatar", 
        "category": "Movie", 
        "id": "82771544063", 
        "created_time": "2012-04-13T21:16:56+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "HappyDance", 
        "category": "Movie", 
        "id": "243564344063", 
        "created_time": "2012-04-13T21:16:56+0000"
      } 
    ], 
    "paging": {
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=5546653546361"
    }
}
```

In PHP, I want to extract all the id numbers from the rows that show

```
"id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
```

The output should look like this:

```
I like 8277564344063
I like 243564344063
```

I started the following but I am getting an error:

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("raw.txt", "rb");
ob_start();

$text = file_get_contents('raw.txt');
$decode = json_decode($text);

print_r($decode);

$new_content = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents("likes.txt", $new_content);

fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

The error is that my output is blank! What am I doing wrong?

Please help?

Comment: I think your writing this code as if it were C++ use file get contents.

Comment: Using file_get_contents() now, but I'm getting errors. Care to look at my updated code?

Comment: check my answer out. are you trying to write to a text file with the comma seperated list of id's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have valid JSON.

The JSON **Object** below this line is valid JSON. I removed the comma after your last associative array within your "data" array. You shouldn't need a comma at the end of the array.

```
        {
            "data": [
              {
                "name": "Avatar", 
                "category": "Movie", 
                "id": "82771544063", 
                "created_time": "2012-04-13T21:16:56+0000"
              }, 
              {
                "name": "HappyDance", 
                "category": "Movie", 
                "id": "243564344063", 
                "created_time": "2012-04-13T21:16:56+0000"
              }
            ], 
            "paging": {
                "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes? format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=5546653546361"
            }
        }


Parse error on line 14:
...    },            ],    "paging": { 
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

As I removed the comma from the non-valid JSON. I was able to get the result you wanted.

```
            <?php
                $json_object = file_get_contents('fb.json');
                if(!$json_object) {
                                      echo "oops, cant read the file";
                                    }

                 // remap json_object
                 $json_object = json_decode($json_object,true);

                    foreach($json_object['data'] as $item) {
                            $items[] = "I like" . ' ' . $item['id'];

                      /* If you want to just echo " I like xyz" etc
                       * use echo "I like" . $item['id'];
                       */
                        }

                  $list = implode(',',$items);

                  echo $list;
            ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting two errors: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in readlikes.php on line 7 and Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in readlikes.php on line 15

Comment: Well, was that JSON the exact same file as the file you gave in your question? If not, then you should verify that the json is valid. The above code works for the data that you you gave.

Comment: The file is a TXT file. I renamed it to fb.json but the errors persist. The layout of the file is exactly as I posted.

Comment: What does the file look like? Is it the same **exact** structure as the struture you provided in the question?

Comment: Yes it is. I even copied and pasted it in a new "raw.txt" file, comma removed and approved as valid jSON at jsonlint.com. I'm using a new php file with your code copied and pasted, having changed fb.json for raw.txt. I did try naming my txt file to fb.json but that didn't solve the errors.

Comment: check to see that your able to open the file stream.

Comment: Finally figured it out. The file was saving as Unicode instead of ANSI. I changed that and everything worked out. Thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: Argh! Curious anomaly: I've pasted the full length of the JSON in my file, about 10,000 lines (same format, just lots of data) and the errors returned. jsonlint valides it okay... Is there some sort of memory limit? I can only get it to work when there's less than 10 records.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10076/discussion-between-rpm-and-jonathan)